# How to delete single row using a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, triggers

I created a trigger for restricting the deletion of record from the `database` in `sql` server. This is my query for creating the `trigger`

```
create trigger del on details
for delete
as begin
rollback tran
end
```

This trigger restricts the user from deleting the record. But now, I want to create a `trigger` which allows the user to delete the record one by one, not all at a time . How can I do this using a `trigger`.

Comment: Is it for MySQL or MSSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using (inside the trigger code):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Deleted
```

If larger than 1, rollback. You could also check if `@@ROWCOUNT > 1` and then rollback if it is.

Comment: You should throw an error instead of rolling back the transaction, otherwise it will be hard to identify this scenario when troubleshooting application code.

Comment: Good comment (I was just trying to help with the specific task of preventing multiple row updates).